# Best way to debug the classloader when it isn't finding a property file

Tags: java-8, classpath

I'm deploying a jar which I believe has been packaged acceptably.

all the files except META-INF/MANIFEST.MF are in a single folder /share

so in the jar is is essentially

```
   META-INF/
   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   share/
   share/file21.class
   ...
   share/some.properties
```

in the code I'm trying to load the properties from file21.class

```
try {
    logger.error("@@@@@@@@1");
    InputStream in = File21.class.getResourceAsStream("/some.properties");
    logger.error("@@@@@@@@2");
    this.prop.load(in);
    in.close();
    // this.prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/some.properties"));
    logger.error("@@@@@@@@3");
...

} catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.error("error", ex);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("general exception", e);
}
```

I have tried some variations and I never get to log point 3.  I get

> general exception: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> share.Class.(GetPropertyException.java:93)

Is there an easy way to see where the class loader is looking and where I should point it (or put the file) I'm using Ant so I'm using a build file to move the property file in the class path.  Or so I thought.

Comment: Since both, the class and the resource, reside in the same virtual folder, you should use `File21.class.getResourceAsStream("some.properties")` without a slash before the resource name. A name starting with slash denotes an absolute path, so you would need `File21.class.getResourceAsStream("/share/some.properties")`, but there would be no sense in doing so. You’re calling the method an a `Class` rather than `ClassLoader` specifically to look up relative to the class location, so provide a relative path. No need to debug the lookup process (so I’m not answering your literal question).

Comment: …and you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of calling `close()` manually, `try(InputStream in = File21.class.getResourceAsStream("some.properties")) { this.prop.load(in); }`